# Replace navigation with Tiles

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, css, design-manager

is there a way to replace the default navigation that is the the list below with tile version. Basically just remove that list and put a tiles in two columns as shown below.I found that sharepoint promoted links can be used but Please show me the css too,i cant figured out how to style those tiles in two columns.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to Use the SharePoint Promoted Links and then apply some CSS to manages the design and alignment.

Comment: Can you provide additional details on how you want to accomplish this? I see a list under the Recent heading called Metro Tiles; did you want to use a list as the source of links?

Comment: I just need basically  4 image rather than the list shown. @wjervis

Comment: In that case, simply change the links to be the ones you want, and use CSS to style them as needed.  Unfortunately, I'm rubbish with CSS, so can't provide any pointers there.

Comment: @wjervis this is exactly what i need the css

Comment: @RohitWaghela can you show me the css please

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how custom you want to go, you can add a code snippet to hide the left navigation altogether, add a web part and customize your css/html on Classic pages. Here's a snippet for that:

```
<style type="text/css">
#sideNavBox { display: none; }
#contentBox { margin-left: 20px; }
</style>
```

If you're on SP Online, you can create a modern page and add the [Hero web part](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Use-the-Hero-web-part-d57f449b-19a0-4b0d-8ce3-be5866430645) to it.

Good luck.

Comment: am using the classic sharepoint experience,i dont think Hero web part is available here,

Comment: I understand that issue so well!  One other option you can try is to download Olivier Carpentier's Fantastic 40 SharePoint Web Parts*.  They're SP Framework, so designed for modern pages, but many of them work on classic pages - like the image related ones.  There is an image tile one that works on classic site pages.  
*https://github.com/OlivierCC/spfx-40-fantastics

Comment: i am using a modern experience now,how do i resize those hero tiles now?

Comment: Aha!  On a modern page, add the Hero web part.  It is an OOTB web part; not one you'd have to import.  Then with the web part on the page, you can customize layout options - more details here.  Good luck!    https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-Hero-web-part-d57f449b-19a0-4b0d-8ce3-be5866430645

Comment: i did play with the layout and number of tiles but i cant seem to be able to resize the webpart which is was possible in classic experience where i put the height and width of the webpart. Here i cant find that option

Comment: Yes, that option is not available.  I've re-read the thread and it sounds like you'd like basically two columns - with two tiles each, and to not see the left navigation. So a modern page in a traditional site would still contain the left navigation, unless you create a modern Team or Communications site.  If you're using a Classic site, you can add the CSS via code snippet above to hide the left navigation, then edit your site home page and add a 2x2 table and insert the hyperlinked tiles into that.   Hope that helps - good luck!

Comment: am just getting started with css branding and i found out that the only way to make modification is by using the ID.Is there any css template available freely that i can just used. Branding is taking way too much time as i have to to style each single DOM element one by one ,is there a better approach?

Comment: I can't really help you there....I try to avoid customizing css/html if at all possible (except in situations where I am added to a project already along in its design phase that refuses to use OOTB).  My client guidance if it were my project would to to strongly encourage the use of OOTB web parts; mock up examples, have the client choose, OR have the client acknowledge that they require customization for that/those elements.  I wish you luck!